# Java Runtime Exec for VBA script with arguments

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am trying to use Runtime exec() to run a vba script with arguements. I am having trouble passing in the args. I think I need to use the String[] overloaded method for exec.

Currently this works:

```
String command = "cmd /c \"\\concat2.vbs\""

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

But I want to run that with arguments and if I do this

```
String command = "cmd /c \"\\concat2.vbs\" " + arg1 + " " + arg2
```

where arg1 and arg2 are strings my program doesnt run (status = 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think I need to use the String[]
>   overloaded method for exec

Exactly! Change your command to be a String array. The array must contain the command and its arguments:

```
String[] command = {"cmd","/c", "concat2.vbs", arg1, arg2};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

`concat2.vbs` should be on Window's execution path (same directory, or configured in the PATH environment variable)

Check out the [documentation for the Runtime class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29).

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
String[] cmd = { "cmd", "/c", "concat2.vbs" "dog" "house" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Should produce 'doghouse'