# how to execute a script using java code at runtime

Tags: java, scripting, nsis, runtime.exec

I have a **Java application and a NSIS script**. I need to run the NSIS script via Java code at runtime. I know  the following code is used for runtime execution.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec();
```

My problem is **i don't know** how to execute my script with in **exec()**. if anyone please tells me how I use this script with in my exe.

My NSIS script is:

```
OutFile "Your ComputerName.exe"
Name "Your ComputerName"
Caption "ComputerName"
XPStyle "on"

Function .onInit
  ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName" "ComputerName"
  StrCmp $0 "" win9x
  StrCpy $1 $0 4 3
  MessageBox MB_OK "Your ComputerName : $0" 
  Goto done
win9x:
  ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName" "ComputerName"
  StrCpy $1 $0 4 3
  MessageBox MB_OK "Your ComputerName : $0" 
done:
  Quit ; placed here so we quit the installer; we dont need the other pages for this example.
FunctionEnd

Section "-boo"
;
SectionEnd

; rest of script
```

Thanks in Advance..

Hi i use the following java code:

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class SampleClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    Process p;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            r.exec("makensis.exe myscript.nsi");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and my NSIS script is same as above, while i'm executing i got the following error,\

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "makensis.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at SampleClass.main(SampleClass.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Why it happens how to resolve this error?????

Comment: Do you need to run the script with elevated privileges?

Comment: See also similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859537/java-runtime-exec-for-vba-script-with-arguments and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146727/runtime-getruntime-exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with NSIS script, but quick Googling showed me I can run the NSIS script like this in command prompt:`makensis.exe myscript.nsi`

So in java you can do this:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("makensis.exe myscript.nsi")
```

then you can use `p` to get the stdout and stderr text of the execution result. For this to work though you have to make sure `makensis.exe` is under the directory in your `PATH` environmental variable.

Comment: Hi Alvin, my script is in this "C:\Users\FSSD\workspace\Snake\sample.nsi" path how will i give

Comment: oh in this case you can do:
String command = "makensis.exe C:\Users\FSSD\workspace\Snake\sample.nsi"
then, Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)

Comment: Hi Alvin, i use this cmd, My console is in empty, there is no error and there is no output.

Comment: Oh yes, the console will be empty. To the get output you have to use p.outputStream and p.errorStream to get the input and output. Here is the javadoc for the Process class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer on your question, but what you want to achieve with that can be done in Java as well.

Use this code, together with the class attached:

```
String value = WinRegistry.readString (
    WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,                                     // HKEY
   "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName",  // Key
   "ComputerName");                                                   //ValueName
System.out.println("Computer Name = " + value);
```

You need a tricky class which is used to work with the Windows Registry: `WinRegistry.java`

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class WinRegistry {
  public static final int HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 0x80000001;
  public static final int HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;
  public static final int REG_SUCCESS = 0;
  public static final int REG_NOTFOUND = 2;
  public static final int REG_ACCESSDENIED = 5;

  private static final int KEY_ALL_ACCESS = 0xf003f;
  private static final int KEY_READ = 0x20019;
  private static Preferences userRoot = Preferences.userRoot();
  private static Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
  private static Class<? extends Preferences> userClass = userRoot.getClass();
  private static Method regOpenKey = null;
  private static Method regCloseKey = null;
  private static Method regQueryValueEx = null;
  private static Method regEnumValue = null;
  private static Method regQueryInfoKey = null;
  private static Method regEnumKeyEx = null;
  private static Method regCreateKeyEx = null;
  private static Method regSetValueEx = null;
  private static Method regDeleteKey = null;
  private static Method regDeleteValue = null;

  static {
    try {
      regOpenKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegOpenKey",
          new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class, int.class });
      regOpenKey.setAccessible(true);
      regCloseKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegCloseKey",
          new Class[] { int.class });
      regCloseKey.setAccessible(true);
      regQueryValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryValueEx",
          new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class });
      regQueryValueEx.setAccessible(true);
      regEnumValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegEnumValue",
          new Class[] { int.class, int.class, int.class });
      regEnumValue.setAccessible(true);
      regQueryInfoKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryInfoKey1",
          new Class[] { int.class });
      regQueryInfoKey.setAccessible(true);
      regEnumKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegEnumKeyEx", new Class[] { int.class, int.class,  
              int.class });  
      regEnumKeyEx.setAccessible(true);
      regCreateKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegCreateKeyEx", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class });  
      regCreateKeyEx.setAccessible(true);  
      regSetValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegSetValueEx", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class, byte[].class });  
      regSetValueEx.setAccessible(true); 
      regDeleteValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegDeleteValue", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class });  
      regDeleteValue.setAccessible(true); 
      regDeleteKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegDeleteKey", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class });  
      regDeleteKey.setAccessible(true); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private WinRegistry() {  }

  /**
   * Read a value from key and value name
   * @param hkey   HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @param valueName
   * @return the value
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static String readString(int hkey, String key, String valueName) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readString(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readString(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Read value(s) and value name(s) form given key 
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @return the value name(s) plus the value(s)
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static Map<String, String> readStringValues(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readStringValues(systemRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readStringValues(userRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Read the value name(s) from a given key
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @return the value name(s)
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static List<String> readStringSubKeys(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readStringSubKeys(systemRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readStringSubKeys(userRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Create a key
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void createKey(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int [] ret;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      ret = createKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
      regCloseKey.invoke(systemRoot, new Object[] { new Integer(ret[0]) });
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      ret = createKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
      regCloseKey.invoke(userRoot, new Object[] { new Integer(ret[0]) });
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
    if (ret[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + ret[1] + "  key=" + key);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Write a value in a given key/value name
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @param valueName
   * @param value
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void writeStringValue
    (int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      writeStringValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      writeStringValue(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Delete a given key
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void deleteKey(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc = -1;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      rc = deleteKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      rc = deleteKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key);
    }
  }

  /**
   * delete a value from a given key/value name
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @param value
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void deleteValue(int hkey, String key, String value) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc = -1;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      rc = deleteValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, value);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      rc = deleteValue(userRoot, hkey, key, value);
    }
    if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key + "  value=" + value);
    }
  }

  // =====================

  private static int deleteValue
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS) });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return handles[1];  // can be REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED
    }
    int rc =((Integer) regDeleteValue.invoke(root,  
        new Object[] { 
          new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value) 
          })).intValue();
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return rc;
  }

  private static int deleteKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc =((Integer) regDeleteKey.invoke(root,  
        new Object[] { new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key) })).intValue();
    return rc;  // can REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED, REG_SUCCESS
  }

  private static String readString(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ) });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null; 
    }
    byte[] valb = (byte[]) regQueryValueEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value) });
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return (valb != null ? new String(valb).trim() : null);
  }

  private static Map<String,String> readStringValues
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<String,String>();
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ) });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null;
    }
    int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root,
        new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });

    int count = info[2]; // count  
    int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
    for(int index=0; index<count; index++)  {
      byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumValue.invoke(root, new Object[] {
          new Integer
            (handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)});
      String value = readString(hkey, key, new String(name));
      results.put(new String(name).trim(), value);
    }
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return results;
  }

  private static List<String> readStringSubKeys
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ) 
        });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null;
    }
    int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root,
        new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });

    int count = info[2]; // count  
    int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
    for(int index=0; index<count; index++)  {
      byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumKeyEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {
          new Integer
            (handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)
          });
      results.add(new String(name).trim());
    }
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return results;
  }

  private static int [] createKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    return  (int[]) regCreateKeyEx.invoke(root,
        new Object[] { new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key) });
  }

  private static void writeStringValue 
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS) });

    regSetValueEx.invoke(root,  
        new Object[] { 
          new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(valueName), toCstr(value) 
          }); 
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
  }

  // utility
  private static byte[] toCstr(String str) {
    byte[] result = new byte[str.length() + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      result[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
    }
    result[str.length()] = 0;
    return result;
  }
}
```

(Taken from [David's answer on a StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java/6163701#6163701))